# How to pass in parsed datetime into UTC to EST conversion in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I've been stuck on this error for hours. Basically I'm trying to convert a UTC timestamp over to an EST timestamp. However, instead of just passing in a plain timestamp like '2022-05-06 11:28:21',
I'm passing in a parsed timestamp, and this converts it to a text type which no longer works with the UTC to EST conversion function. I've tried typecasting but not sure what I'm doing wrong.

If I have something like:

`SELECT ((timestamp '2022-05-06 11:28:21') AT time zone 'UTC') AT time zone 'EST'`

This works if I'm just passing in an individual timestamp like '2022-05-06 11:18:21', but what I'm doing is parsing a timestamp column, doing something like REPLACE(TimeStampColumn,' ',''). So basically now my query is

`SELECT ((timestamp REPLACE(TimeStampColumn,' ','')) AT time zone 'UTC') AT time zone 'EST'`

When I do this, I now get a type error. I tried casting the parsed TimeStamp Column to a timestamp type but no luck. Need some help.

Comment: `replace` works on strings (text, varchar), not on timestamps. Also the `timestamp` keyword is only required when writing constant values. `select timestampcolumn at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'EST` should work

Comment: 1) What is the data type for the timestamp column, `timestamp` or `timestamptz`? 2) What does `show timezone;` return? **Add answers as update to question**.